# How to test a successful release prior to allowing PR to complete?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pull-request, azure-repos

I know that build validation policy can be set on branch and it will trigger a PR build that will ensure that it succeeds.

Is there any way to test a successful release prior to allowing PR to complete? There is the following status policy option - but it shows an empty dropdown.

[image: status policy]

Comment: Are you using multi-stage pipelines or the classic release pipelines?

Comment: Classic. But appreciate answer for both will be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running a classic pipeline there are a few steps that are required, as documented in the [Microsoft docs: Deploy pull request builds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deploy-pull-request-builds)

*In short:* You are on the right track with the status policy. It could be empty because the release has not yet run, or it has run but not with the correct setting.

You need to toggle Pull Request Deployment on a stage in your release pipeline, for example on the Dev stage. The picture is taken from the above mentioned docs.

[image: set Pull request deployment]

After you've enabled that toggle, you should run the release once and afterwards, the status should appear as an option in your policies, which you can then set as a required condition.

For a complete step by step, you can follow the above mentioned Microsoft documentation.